# Foreach php loop to display html unordered list of mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to display unordered lists made with sql table columns but i get empty lists which i don't get because when i type

```
echo $stories[0]['title'];
```

i get the value expected (jason).

I have tried with and without echo but the result is the same..

here is my table :

```
mysql> select * from story;

+----+-------+-------------------------+---------+ 
| id | title | content                 | author  |
+----+-------+-------------------------+---------+ 
|  1 | jason | histoire des argonautes | guigous | 
|  2 | jason | histoire des argonautes | guigous |
```

and my html :

```
<?php
require 'connec.php';
$pdo = new PDO(DSN,USER,PASS);

$query ='select * from story';
$statement = $pdo->query($query);
$stories= $statement->fetchAll();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<?php 
echo $stories[0]['title'];
for ($i=0; count($stories)>$i; $i++) :
?>  
    <ul>
        <li> <? echo $stories[$i]['title']?></li>
        <li><? echo $stories[$i]['content']?></li>
        <li><? echo $stories[$i]['author']?></li>
    </ul> 
<?php endfor; ?>
</body>
```

thanks you for your time !

Comment: Maybe use <?php rather than <?

Comment: just tried it and it sadly doesn't work

Comment: To be safe, I would also wrap in htmlspecialchars(), ie <?php echo htmlspecialchars($stories[$i]['title']); ?>

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here, check your server logs for errors. Also, what HTML gets output?

Comment: Do you get an unordered list with empty <li> elements, or no list at all?

Comment: i get the lists, te rightful number of lists, but they are all blank

Comment: Not sure whether this is important, but have you got semicolons at the end of your echo statements?

Comment: I recommend using `foreach` to loop over an array, instead of `for`.

Comment: @RobEyre The semicolon is optional there.

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($stories);`?

Comment: @Barmar i see something too long to type in one comment but basically if i cut the second half i see :

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => int 1
      0 => int 1
      'title' => string 'jason' (length=5)
      1 => string 'jason' (length=5)
      'content' => string 'histoire des argonautes' (length=23)
      2 => string 'histoire des argonautes' (length=23)
      'author' => string 'guigous' (length=7)
      3 => string 'guigous' (length=7)

Comment: Using a `foreach` instead of a `for` loop works a lot better and cleaner.

Comment: The main issue is whether you see the expected contents or not. If that shows the array, I can't see any reason why you don't see it in the list.

Comment: If you do View Source, do you see the expected contents in the lists? If so, it sounds like a CSS problem.

Comment: @RobEyre ok so i tested again and the <?php trick worked. I guess the end of the day and me no type what want to type were playing some tricks against I. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code, not sure is correct or not, also it will be great if you can provide exported `SQL` table so we can replicate the environment

But meanwhile you can try this code:

```
<?php
for(int $i = 0; $i < count($stories); $i++) {
  ?>
   <ul>
     <li><?php echo $stories[$i]['id']; ?></li>
     <li><?php echo $stories[$i]['title']; ?></li>
     <li><?php echo $stories[$i]['content']; ?></li>
     <li><?php echo $stories[$i]['author']; ?></li>
   </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: the int $i made a parse error so i tried without the int and it worked. Don't know why but it did
Good job !

Comment: i doublechecked and its the <?php at the beggining that made it work. Thank you :)

Comment: @MaëlEtienne <?php ?> is required if you are trying to inject some php code, sorry about int $i did not code in php for a while